# Possibility to enable the email verification on only a part of users?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

We have two types of accounts in our company. One user type (type1) are the one that we create manually via an internal UI. Now we want to give the possibility to clients to register themselves from a public UI (type2).

We would like to activate the registration process for users of "type2" and disable it for users of "type1". Is it possible to control it somehow?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've discovered this REST API function:
https://host/parse/verificationEmailRequest

But unfortunately, it does not work for my use case. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you add a description why the -1? please?

Comment: There isn't a setup for it in Parse Server, but I believe you can enable email verification for all users and create a beforeSave trigger for the User class and set users type 1 with field emailVerified=true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there is no such option on parse-server but as @Davi Macedo posted it's possible to hook on the beforeSave trigger of the user and sent the verified flag to true. What I did, instead, is to check on the email adapter what kind of user request to send email and block when the user is of "type1". Maybe the solution from @Davi Macedo is more elegant but also the second one was working fine for me for now. Thanks a lot for helping out!